# java8 - Optional- How to use it correctly?

Tags: java, option-type

The cityStr is a String, and it would be a null or "". I want to turn it to a int and if it's greater than 0, then I will print "the city is exist".

```
 if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cityStr)) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(cityStr) > 0) {
            System.out.println("the city is exist");
        }
 }
```

I want to used the below code to replace the above code, but I got a exception. How can I use it correctly? Thanks so much for your answer.

```
    if (Optional.ofNullable(cityStr)
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .filter(city -> city > 0)
            .isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("the city is exist");
    }
```

And the below is the exception information:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
```

Comment: I personally do not think that `Optional` adds much here. It was mainly developed as return type for methods that have to indicate that they do not always return something. Prime-example would be a `find` method. And not really as logic-tool to wrap around your variable to use its chained commands. In your specific case, I think it only bloats the code unecessarily and makes it harder to see what you are actually doing (just checking `Integer.parseInt(...) > 0`). If you want to increase readability, create a helper method.

Comment: Note that use of `isPresent()` is a code smell; prefer `ifPresent`/`ifPresentOrElse` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to parse a number from an empty String. That throws the exception. It has nothing to do with Optional.

Maybe you thought that an empty string would be 'nullish' - like an empty String being falsy in javascript.

To get rid of the exception, assign `null` or a number to `cityStr`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as :

```
String cityStr = null;
if (Optional.ofNullable(cityStr)
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .filter(city -> city > 0)
        .isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("the city is exist");
}
```

If you are expecting non numeric string you've to handle that yourself in the `map` method.

Comment: yes, even i was thinking the same instead of using Integer.parseInt we need to have a method that wraps it up and on runtime exception return 0 from there on normal flow would return, correct my approach if it is missing something.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @fastcodejava I made minor changes to the program, please take a look below:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String cityStr = "1";

        Optional<String> cityOptional = Optional.ofNullable(cityStr)
                .map(MainClass::parseInt)
                .filter(integer -> integer > 0)
                .map(integer -> "city exists");

        String cityString = cityOptional.orElse("city does not exists");
        System.out.println(cityString);


    }

    public static int parseInt(String str) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Eating e for unknown reason
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Where `MainClass` is the class for main method MainClass.java

Comment: Imo your `parseInt` should return `OptionalInt`, that is **exactly** what the class was developed for. To stop returning bad sentinel values that can easily be forgotten about, to reduce bugs, to favor fail-fast. And after all, otherwise your method can not parse the legit value `-1` anymore. In which case you should at least rename it `parsePositiveInt`